# Converting boolean to BitSet in Java

Tags: java, arrays, boolean, bitset

So I before had this:

```
public static final boolean opaqueCubeLookup = new boolean[4096];
```

But I found out that BitSet it much better at managing memory, so I changed it to this:

```
public static final BitSet opaqueCubeLookup = new BitSet(4096);
```

I also had this code:

```
opaqueCubeLookup[par1] = this.isOpaqueCube();
```

But after moving to BitSet I have problem, I get this error:

```
The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to BitSet
```

How can I fix it?
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Note that according to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605451/2071828) SO answer `BitSet` is significantly slower (4x). Swings and roundabouts eh?

Comment: @bmorris591 Is 4096 objects considered small, cause after some testing it seems to have 2x less FPS but takes less CPU and memory (I mean the optimized seems slower)

Comment: In the linked thread the benchmark is done with 1 million items, the post says that performance is equal when this reaches 4 million. I guess that means 4096 is (very) small...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
opaqueCudeLookup.set(par1, this.isOpaqueCube());
```

See [BitSet.html#set(int, boolean)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#set%28int,%20boolean%29)

Comment: Thanks, this worked! Should boost my app perfomance a lot! :)

Comment: @tambre performance, no - it will be slower. Memory footprint will be less however.

Comment: @bmorris591 Just noticed it...Damn! I spent over 1hour converting it!

Comment: @tambre: In order to facilitate switching, make an interface with two implementations: one backed by a BitSet and one backed by a bool array. This way you can switch without so much effort.

Comment: @bmorris591: I wouldn't assume that, though it's quite possible.  Improved memory caching effects, for example, might outweigh the cost of the bit-twiddling -- if an entire `BitSet` fits into your L1 cache, where a `boolean[]` would not, then it's not at all clear which would win.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
opaqueCubeLookup.set(part1, this.isOpaqueCube());
```