# In Java, is there anything that works like an array but takes less memory?

Tags: java, arrays, genetic-algorithm

I'm programming a genetic algorithm. Right now, I'm using arrays for everything: my individuals are composed of arrays of ints, my populations are arrays of individuals, I store information inside an array to keep track of it.

A huge limitation I'm encountering is running out of memory. I know GAs are memory intensive, but i wonder if my first step should be to make an easy change, by using something better than an array.

Comment: Nope, that's as low level as you can get.

Comment: Are your arrays sparse?

Comment: I can't think of a more efficient way of storing a large number of ints than an array of ints.  But do they need to be ints?  Are you using all 32 bits?  Or would shorts or bytes be an option?

Comment: @MattBall Out of curiosity, what were you going to suggest if they were?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis really depends on the use case. Anything from a `Map`/`Set` to a `BitSet` to a bloom filter.

Comment: How much memory are you giving the JVM? Could you... just give it more? That would be _by far_ the easiest change to make.

Comment: @DavidWallace, no, I'm only storing 0s and 1s... I should really change my ints to bytes. Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: If they're only 0s and 1s then use a `BitSet`.

Comment: @MattBall, yes, I've tried giving more memory to the JVM. The memory demands of the genetic algorithm are getting rather ridiculous, though, so I'm trying to make my code better.

Comment: How much RAM do you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question depends a lot on the nature of your data.

If you have sparse data (mostly 0's and very few 1's or vice versa), then creating an array of *indices* of 1's might do the trick for you. As David Wallace mentioned, a HashSet of indices would allow you to quickly check whether a particular index is 1 or 0.

If you do not have sparse data, then you might want a BitSet.

This [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605226/boolean-vs-bitset-which-is-more-efficient) might also be useful to give you input.

Comment: For sparse data, a `HashSet` of indices might work better than an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a triplet into one integer.

G = 0001

A = 0010

T = 0011

C = 0100

U = 0101 (RNA)

N = 0111 (G or C)

Q = 1000 (A or T/U)

...

3 x 4 bits fits in one 32 bit int. A triplet fits good into the genetic context.
Write a Helper class to encode/decode the base and add it to an list array. Consider initial size and load factor.